# swift sort through array and get data from elements

Tags: swift, xcode

wanting to have code that goes a little like this

```
var latitude: String?

 var longitude: String?

 func getMyCitiesCordinates(city:String){
  if city == "Adelaide"{
  self.latitude = -34.9286600
  self.longitude = 138.5986300
  }
```

but instead of doing a

if city==

for each city to get the lat and long i would just like a function like below where it searches through the array to find the matching City/String and returns the latitude and longitude of that city?

```
 func getLatAndLong(myCity:String){

  let citiesArray = ["Adelaide": CLLocation(latitude: -34.9286600, longitude: 138.5986300),"Albury": CLLocation(latitude: -36.0737, longitude: 146.9135),"Alice Springs": CLLocation(latitude: -23.6980, longitude: 133.8807),"Armadale": CLLocation(latitude: -32.1530, longitude: 116.0150),"Ballarat": CLLocation(latitude: -37.5622, longitude: 143.8503),"Brisbane": CLLocation(latitude: -27.470125, longitude: 153.021072),"Bunbury": CLLocation(latitude: -33.3256, longitude: 115.6396)]
}
```

then it returns the lat and long for that city?
latitude = ?
longitude = ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   class city: NSObject {
       var city: String
       var longitude: Double?
       var latitude: Double?

        init(city: String, latitude: Double?, longitude: Double?) {
         self.city = city
         self.longitude = longitude
         self.latitude = latitude
        }
   }
   var latitude: Double?
   var dict: [String:CLLocation]
   var longitude: Double?
   var dict = citiesArray


   func viewDidLoad {
   city = getMyCitiesCordinates(mycity:"Adelaide")
   }



    func getMyCitiesCordinates(mycity:String) -> city{

          let location = dict[mycity]
          return city(city: mycity, latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

      }
```

Comment: There are many problems with this code, for starters I think you should compile it.

Comment: I just gave the idea. I wrote it on my phone. it says the logic not the spoon feed

Comment: I don't think that is an acceptable excuse for posting substandard code, specially when OP is clearly a beginner.

Comment: Its not an excuse because I don't need any and let OP decide what he wants to do with the code.

Comment: and I don't think there is any problem in the code logic if you can understand it. if not then I can't help. And OP seems to understand the logic so he will be able to understand it and that's all I want.

Comment: anyone else with an answer I can copy paste?

Comment: This code still doesn't compile and is badly formatted. I know you have gotten your points but this answer is not only for OP but also for other people that might research a similar question in the future so you need to clean it up.